# Limiting the number of characters per line with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph of text:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
```

How can I make sure that no more than 30 characters are shown on one line with CSS?

Comment: I possibly would help if you said why you need to do this.

Comment: It's part of a kinda odd class assignment. Not my idea. From the book Programming The World Wide Web 2009: "The document must have a paragraph of at least 20 lines of text that describe you. This paragraph must be centered on the page and have space for 30 characters per line only. (...)"

Comment: Oh, you want a 30 characters maximum, not exactly 30 characters per line. I guess the book is going for `width: 30em`, although that is not really exactly correct. My guess would be that it's a badly written question (or even a badly written book).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can set the width of the `p` to as much as 30 characters and next letters will automatically come down but again this won't be that accurate and will vary if the characters are in capital. Just see this example:

```css
    p {
      max-width: 30ch;
    }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: So how would I go about doing this in JS? Is it complicated or is it just a one-liner?

Comment: @Pieter: you can use the javascript's `substr` function for that i suppose and it won't be a single liner (unless a regex might do the trick) but i would suggest you to just setting the width of the paragraph if the requirement is not that strict.

Comment: +1 That is how I solve this problem -- only annoyance, most fonts are variable width, so if some wonderful person puts in MMMMMMMM... they usually break your design or have overflow. If you make the <p> the width of 30 Ms, then there is ofter a lot of space at the end of the div. You need to make a judgement call.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The correct answer is to set the max-width property to some number of "ex" units. For example, max-width: 30ex should do what the question requires.

Comment: @Christopher The question is to limit the number of characters, not the width of the paragraph. Characters have different widths. You could argue that setting max-width would be a better idea, but it's not the question at hand.

Answer (score 84):

You could do this:
*(**Note**! This is CSS3 and the browser support = good!! )*

```css
p {
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* will make [...] at the end */
    width: 370px; /* change to your preferences */
    white-space: nowrap; /* paragraph to one line */
    overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
    }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: Hint: Using `max-width: XXXpx;` is the better choice for dynamic tables.

Comment: Something that isn't immediately clear is that this does not seem to work on all HTML elements. At first, I had an anchor element and it would not work as designed.

Comment: I like `max-width` too. Along with `em` this can be made scalable too. This method will depend on how big the developer makes the font; a reasonable facsimile can be made though: `p { max-width:40em; }`.

Answer (score 20):

The latest way to go is to use the unit 'ch' which stands for character.

You can simply write:

`p {
  max-width: 75ch;
}`

The only trick is that whitespaces won't be counted as characters..

Check also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26975271/4069992

Comment: Notice that `ch` represents the width of the 0 character in the given font. In monospace fonts, all the characters will have the same width, so adding `max-width: 75ch` will effectively limit the number of characters per line to 75. But in non-monospace fonts the letter count may differ from line to line (as the i is narrower than the m, for example).

Answer (score 10):

If you use CSS to select a monospace font, the problem of varying character length is easily solved.

Comment: But impacts your visual design.

Comment: Developer vs Designer! Fight!

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but… how is it “easily solved”? :)

Comment: @mhulse A monospaced font has the same width in pixles for every character, so it's a simple math operation to know what's the width you have to use depending on the text length.

Comment: This didn't age well

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what font you're using you can set `max-width` on the paragraph with a calculated value. It will not be exact, but I've found that in most cases that does not matter.

```
p {
  max-width: calc(30em * 0.5);
}
```

The number you multiply with depends on what font it is, and how much a character takes up in a em square. More characters = less accurate.

Comment: This could be the accepted answer. Easy solution using only CSS.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be you use in style css, the command to break lines. Works in older versions of browsers.

```
p {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw lots of answers above and its work.

In addition, This also works for me.

```
p {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP asked how to limit the number of characters per line with CSS and not JavaScript, but I see some comments like Pieter's asking as to how this can also be done in JS.

A lot of accepted solutions out there seem to be using CSS with the `text-overflow` property and `width` using character-units (`ch`).
This is a good solution but maybe we would like to handle it precisely char by char.
Perhaps even you'll find my solution easier to work with than a bunch of CSS properties and rules!
Anywho, just to let you know, my solution stems from Josh's answer in this post:
[How to limit the length of text in a paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447269/how-to-limit-the-length-of-text-in-a-paragraph).
I believed Josh was onto something with their idea to use JS and decided to take it a step further.

**Okay, let's talk JS and pseudocode:**

If we think about the problem at hand here, generally the idea is to limit the number of characters on each "line" in the
paragraph's text string. This would essentially prevent your text from overflowing or going out of bounds.
But as we may know, paragraph text strings themselves are just one long line of text so we have to define what a "line"
is for the problem's solution. What better way to define a "line" than with a "newline" character! (Ok, that was a bit cheesy).
But you get the point. We'll stop the amount of characters on each line in the paragraph's text using newlines or `\n`.

For the implementation, I thought this would be ugly to code iteratively and I was just "feeling" the recursive route.
If you're unfamiliar with recursion, all I am doing is making the function or method call itself and smash down the
call stack until it reaches my defined base case, the end of the road to say that we have solved it!

Here's version 1, where it simply appends a newline character if the current substring is longer than our max char limit
length; else, it just goes to the end and eventually the length, or one past the last valid char index, is reached.

```js
/*=======================*/
/*Made by: Brendan Sting */
/*=======================*/

/* ---Limit text inside a <p> tag with vanilla JavaScript, version 1; bad wrapping/cutoff--- */

function truncateText(selector, maxLength, startAt) {
    var element = document.querySelector(selector);
    var truncated = element.innerText;
    
    // BASE CASE:
    if (startAt >= truncated.length)
    {
        return "";
    }
        
    // If the currently looked at substring is longer than the limit, cut it:
    if (truncated.substring(startAt).length > maxLength) {
        truncated = truncated.substring(startAt, (startAt+maxLength)) + '\n';
    }
    
    // Else, just write it out with no newline needed:
    else
    {
        truncated = truncated.substring(startAt);
    }
    
    // Recursive return:
    return truncated + truncateText(selector, maxLength, (startAt + maxLength));
}

document.querySelector('p').innerText = truncateText('p', 30, 0);
/* --- END OF CODE SNIPPET V1 ---  */
```

```html
<!-- TEST COVERAGE -->

<!--Test case 1: PASS -->
<p>Breaking India: Western Interventions in Dravidian and Dalit Faultlines is a book written by Rajiv Malhotra and Aravindan Neelakandan which argues that India's integrity is being undermined.</p>

<!-- Test case 2: PASS -->
<!--<p>&emsp;Breaking India: Western Interventions in Dravidian and Dalit Faultlines is a book written by Rajiv Malhotra and Aravindan Neelakandan which argues that India's integrity is being undermined.</p> -->

<!-- Test case 3: PASS -->
<!--<p>&emsp;Breaking India: Western Interventions in Dravidian and Dalit Faultlines is a book written by Rajiv Malhotra and Aravindan Neelakandan which argues that India's integrity is being undermined.<br><br>&emsp;Now, what if I started typing down here, huh? Can you handle this text as well?</p> -->

<!--Test case 4: PASS -->
<!--<p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.</p>-->

<!-- Test case 5: PASS -->
<!--<p></p>-->

<!-- Test case 6: PASS -->
<!--<p>12345678910         111213141516170000000000000000000000   1819202122</p> -->

<!-- END OF TESTS -->
```

This is...well, it does what we told it strictly to do. It just cuts off the chars past a limit we define in its query call.
But it can be improved! I don't know about you, but I hate that my words get split up across the different lines.
Instead, a better solution should take from like what Microsoft Word does where each WORD is moved to a newline if the line
exceeds the character limit set on the page. This keeps the word together and keeps our lines at our desired limit!

Alrighty, take two! Let's expand our problem that if the last word on the line is cutoff past the limit, then its whole word should be
moved to the next line for a full-print.

At a glance this seems simple enough, but my other 7 versions of my original version 1 JS code say otherwise. We need to not only accomplish
preserving words while respecting the char limit, but we also need to account for edge-cases such as a really long word that itself
exceeds the limit. To accomplish preserving words while respecting the char limit on each line, we can search for the nearest blank space found
earlier in the paragraph's string and move our ending index, where we'll append the newline character, to that blank space which essentially
puts the word right after the newline! If there's no blank spaces available to resort to, well, we'll just go ahead and cut words normally like
in version 1; but that should never happen as paragraphs are bound to have spaces in them! Furthermore, we can actually use this principle to
handle the edge-case example I mentioned earlier with the really long word via using some helper functions' returns.

Whew, okay, that was a LOT! But I just want to make sure you understand the design of the solution I made.
Now, let's see that final implementation:

```js
/*=======================*/
/*Made by: Brendan Sting */
/*=======================*/

/* --- Limit text inside a <p> tag with vanilla JavaScript; version 8 --- */

/* === LATEST WORKING VERSION === */

// Tries to find the last available blank space to resort to:
function findLastBlankSpaceStartingFrom(inString, startIndex) {
  for (let loopIndex = startIndex; loopIndex > -1; loopIndex--) {
    if (inString[loopIndex] == " ") {
      return loopIndex;
    }
  }

  return -1; // Darn, we couldn't find it; handle it
}

// Frees any chars that have been disconnected from the current substring line by past newline characters (also from <br> tags)
function freeUpAnyNewlineSeparatedCharSpace(inString, upUntilThisPoint, startingFromHere) //upUntilThisPoint = startAt index, startingFromHere = lastCharIndex
{
  var extraAvailableChars = 0;
  let startCountingSwitchEnabled = false;

  if (startingFromHere > upUntilThisPoint) {
    for (let loopIndex = startingFromHere; loopIndex >= upUntilThisPoint; loopIndex--) {
      if (inString[loopIndex] == '\n') {
        startCountingSwitchEnabled = true;
      }

      if (startCountingSwitchEnabled) {
        extraAvailableChars++;
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (let loopIndex = startingFromHere; loopIndex <= upUntilThisPoint; loopIndex++) {
      if (inString[loopIndex] == '\n') {
        startCountingSwitchEnabled = true;
      }

      if (startCountingSwitchEnabled) {
        extraAvailableChars++;
      }
    }
  }

  return extraAvailableChars;
}

function getNewEndpointBeforeLineOverflow(ofThisString, atLastCharIndex, startOfLine) {
  var finalCharIndex = atLastCharIndex;

  // If last char index on the line is below the last char of the entire string, then:
  if (atLastCharIndex < (ofThisString.length - 1)) {
    // If there's a non-blank, non-space character past the last char to limit to, then:
    if ((ofThisString[atLastCharIndex] != ' ') && (ofThisString[atLastCharIndex + 1] != ' ')) {
      // Try and find a previous blank space to resort to and end on:
      var prevBlankIndex = findLastBlankSpaceStartingFrom(ofThisString, (atLastCharIndex));

      if ((prevBlankIndex != -1) && (prevBlankIndex >= startOfLine)) // Did we find a valid blank space within this portion of the line?
      {
        finalCharIndex = prevBlankIndex; //Index of the blank space now
      }
    }
  } else {
    // If the initial overflow index point, the last char point, is past or at the string's final valid char index,
    // then we have no choice but to reposition it at the text's final char index:
    finalCharIndex = (ofThisString.length - 1);
  }

  return finalCharIndex;

}


function truncateText(selector, maxLength, startAt) {
  var element = document.querySelector(selector);
  var truncated = element.innerText;
  let lastCharIndex = (startAt + maxLength) - 1;

  // BASE CASE:
  if (startAt >= truncated.length) {
    return "";
  }
  // If the currently looked at substring is longer than the limit, cut it:
  if (truncated.substring(startAt).length > maxLength) {
    lastCharIndex = getNewEndpointBeforeLineOverflow(truncated, lastCharIndex, startAt);

    var extraLineSpace = freeUpAnyNewlineSeparatedCharSpace(truncated, startAt, lastCharIndex);
    if (extraLineSpace > 0) {
      lastCharIndex = lastCharIndex + extraLineSpace;
      lastCharIndex = getNewEndpointBeforeLineOverflow(truncated, lastCharIndex, startAt)
    }

    truncated = truncated.substring(startAt, (lastCharIndex + 1)); //Stop at either maxLength or blankSpace+1

    // Allow the front-end programmer to input tabs or spaces at the front with &emsp; or &nbsp; (etc.), but if it's a raw space then cut it out:
    // (This conditional structure has been reduced thanks to the power of .innerText)
    if (truncated[startAt] == ' ') {
      truncated = truncated.trim() + '\n';
    } else {
      truncated = truncated.trimEnd() + '\n';
    }

  }

  // Else, just write it out with no newline needed:
  else {
    truncated = truncated.substring(startAt);
  }

  // Recursive return:
  return truncated + truncateText(selector, maxLength, (lastCharIndex + 1));

}

document.querySelector('p').innerText = truncateText('p', 30, 0);
/* --- END OF CODE SNIPPET V8 ---  */
```

```html
<!-- TEST COVERAGE -->

<!--Test case 1: PASS -->
<p>Breaking India: Western Interventions in Dravidian and Dalit Faultlines is a book written by Rajiv Malhotra and Aravindan Neelakandan which argues that India's integrity is being undermined.</p>

<!-- Test case 2: PASS -->
<!--<p>&emsp;Breaking India: Western Interventions in Dravidian and Dalit Faultlines is a book written by Rajiv Malhotra and Aravindan Neelakandan which argues that India's integrity is being undermined.</p> -->

<!-- Test case 3: PASS -->
<!--<p>&emsp;Breaking India: Western Interventions in Dravidian and Dalit Faultlines is a book written by Rajiv Malhotra and Aravindan Neelakandan which argues that India's integrity is being undermined.<br><br>&emsp;Now, what if I started typing down here, huh? Can you handle this text as well?</p> -->

<!--Test case 4: PASS -->
<!--<p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.</p>-->

<!-- Test case 5: PASS -->
<!--<p></p>-->

<!-- Test case 6: PASS -->
<!--<p>12345678910         111213141516170000000000000000000000   1819202122</p> -->

<!-- END OF TESTS -->
```

Note that my JavaScript code utilizes `.innerText` and NOT `.innerHTML` so there shouldn't be any security vulnerabilities with the way it edits your paragraph tag's text!

Hopefully my code and solution helps you out in some way, if at the very least gives you an idea about how to solve it using JavaScript.
**Happy coding and bee cool!**

Answer (score 0):

just css max-inline-size: 66ch, ch===letter
btw it`s nice to have about 45-70ch

Answer (score -7):

Another approach to this would put a ***span*** element with a ***display:block*** style inside the ***p*** element each time you need the content to break. It would only be useful when your ***p*** content is static.

```
<p>this is a not-dynamic text and I want to put<span style="display:block">the following words in the next line</span>and these other words in a third one</p>
```

It would output:

> This is a not-dynamic text and I want to put
>
> the following words in the next line
>
> and these others in a third one

This allows you to change your text line-breaks in different viewports without JS.