# White Space property CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a following td block which present data as follows:

```
My name is Ramya and 
I love football.
I work for ABC Company.

<td style="text-align: left;overflow-wrap:break-word;width:50px;">

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Text)

</td>
```

I want my td to display data like this:

```
My name is Ramya and 
     I love football.
     I work for ABC 
     Company.
```

Which CSS attribute should I use to achieve the result? All the lines which are wrapped should contain some whitespaces.

Comment: style="text-align: right;

Comment: @chillvivek Only from line 2 this property should apply. Will above work? I guess it applies all lines.

Comment: @Nalaka Only from line 2 this property should apply. Will above work? I guess it applies all line

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/69dgkj89/

Comment: @chillvivek I want to manipulate number of whites paces before each line and it should  be the same for all except first line. So text-align: right wotn work for me

Comment: use two td tages with `style="text-align: left` and `style="text-align: right`

Comment: @Nalaka I'm receiving data from one model variable and i'm not sure how big it is. How to divide it into two td? I have given my td above in the question. Could you give me a sample?

Comment: looks like setting the width is the only option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757483/limiting-the-number-of-characters-per-line-with-css

Comment: Do you want the line breaks to appear automatically, where the width of the table cell dictates? Or do you have the line breaks inside your actual content already, as shown, and simply want it to break there, and have the cell width automatically adapt?

Comment: @CBroe I want to break the line , where the width of the table cell dictates and once the content is wrapped when it crosses table cell width it should leave some white space and then start the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [from comments] I want to break the line , where the width of the table cell dictates and once the content is wrapped when it crosses table cell width it should leave some white space and then start the content.

So something like this?

```css
td { width:100px; overflow-wrap:break-word; padding-left:20px;
     text-indent:-20px; text-align:left; background:#fcc; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      My name is Ramya and I love football. I work for ABC Company.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`padding-left:20px;` creates a padding for all the content in the cell, and then `text-indent:-20px;` “drags” the first line back to the left by that same amount.

Comment: This is what I exactly looking for! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is

```
 td{ white-space: pre;  }
```

It will preserve any white-space characters written into your paragraphs.

Here's a good article about it: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

See the MDN documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space