# So I have an HTML file with a paragraph and I need to break into three lines BUT i can only modify the CSS. How do I pull this off? (code below)

Tags: css

```
<form method="post" id="contactForm" action="#">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Newsletter Signup</legend>
            <p>To sign up for our fabulous campaign of useless information that you will never, ever read, please submit your email address here.</p>
            <label for="email" id="emailLabel">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" />
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton"/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

So i need the paragraph to be on three separate lines but it has to be done with CSS.

Comment: You can try adjust the paragraph width.

Comment: duplicate?:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757483/limiting-the-number-of-characters-per-line-with-css

Comment: use `<br>` tag where you want the line break

Comment: @Sumit `but it has to be done with CSS`

Comment: @towerofnix probably other people already provided CSS solution using `width`, I just thought why CSS when something can be done in html itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need it to be in 3 line but don't care where the lines break:

```
p{
  width: 300px;
}
```

But this won't allow you to specify exactly where in the sentence the line breaks.

Comment: What if the font size is 60px?

Comment: then you would have to play with the width until it worked.

Comment: Thanks. :) This was actually what I needed. Sorry I am pretty new to CSS. I will accept your answer once it lets me.